# Changing zoomed chart from linear to log scale is making the axis labels to go huge numbers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I am using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting to plot some graphs. I plot graphs that have scale of 0 to 100 and changing from linear to log scale and log to linear scale is working very well.

Recently, I found a bug where my graph is in linear scale (0 to 100) and is zoomed and if I change it to log scale (0 to 100), the axis labels change to huge numbers (i.e. 7.244E+38) although I have set minimum and maximum value for both x-axis and y-axis. Has anyone come across this kind of issue?

Note: As a hack I am zooming out all the way before changing from one scale to another which solves the issue but the transaction looks very odd.

Comment: Hm, do you really have 0-values in log axes??

Comment: No, I am thresholding values less than or equals to 0 to 0.01.

Comment: You can try to call [`ChartArea.RecalculateAxesScale`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.recalculateaxesscale(v=vs.110).aspx)